# Ikar v'tafel in Mishloach Manot?

Tags: purim, mishloach-manot, ikar-tofel

Mishloach manot must be two foods. Is it acceptable to be one food which is often served as a condiment to the other? For example, sending a roll and chummus.

Comment: If it helps Rav Shlomo Miller of Toronto holds a sandwich is one food (bread + chicken + lettuce). I would guess separate is two foods?

Comment: @robev the mitzva is portions not foods, so that makes sense

Answer (score -1):

**Mishloach Manot** | The mitzvah to send gifts of food is stated in **Esther 9:19** :

> "That is why village Jews, who live in unwalled towns, observe the fourteenth day of the month of Adar and make it a day of merrymaking and feasting, and as a holiday and an occasion for sending gifts to one another." ( עַל־כֵּ֞ן הַיְּהוּדִ֣ים הפרוזים [הַפְּרָזִ֗ים] הַיֹּשְׁבִים֮ בְּעָרֵ֣י הַפְּרָזוֹת֒ עֹשִׂ֗ים אֵ֠ת י֣וֹם אַרְבָּעָ֤ה עָשָׂר֙ לְחֹ֣דֶשׁ אֲדָ֔ר שִׂמְחָ֥ה וּמִשְׁתֶּ֖ה וְי֣וֹם ט֑וֹב וּמִשְׁל֥וֹחַ מָנ֖וֹת אִ֥ישׁ לְרֵעֵֽהוּ )

This obligation is restated in **Esther 9:22** :

> "the same days on which the Jews enjoyed relief from their foes and the same month which had been transformed for them from one of grief and mourning to one of festive joy. They were to observe them as days of feasting and merrymaking, and as an occasion for sending gifts to one another and presents to the poor." ( כַּיָּמִ֗ים אֲשֶׁר־נָ֨חוּ בָהֶ֤ם הַיְּהוּדִים֙ מֵא֣וֹיְבֵיהֶ֔ם וְהַחֹ֗דֶשׁ אֲשֶׁר֩ נֶהְפַּ֨ךְ לָהֶ֤ם מִיָּגוֹן֙ לְשִׂמְחָ֔ה וּמֵאֵ֖בֶל לְי֣וֹם ט֑וֹב לַעֲשׂ֣וֹת אוֹתָ֗ם יְמֵי֙ מִשְׁתֶּ֣ה וְשִׂמְחָ֔ה וּמִשְׁל֤וֹחַ מָנוֹת֙ אִ֣ישׁ לְרֵעֵ֔הוּ וּמַתָּנ֖וֹת לָֽאֶבְיוֹנִֽים )

**Megillah 7a:20**

> וּמַתָּנוֹת לָאֶבְיוֹנִים תָּנֵי רַב יוֹסֵף וּמִשְׁלוֹחַ מָנוֹת אִישׁ לְרֵעֵהוּ שְׁתֵּי מָנוֹת לְאִישׁ אֶחָד וּמַתָּנוֹת לָאֶבְיוֹנִים שְׁתֵּי מַתָּנוֹת לִשְׁנֵי בְּנֵי אָדָם

The mishna mentions: And gifts distributed to the poor. Rav Yosef taught a baraita that the verse states: “And of sending portions one to another” (Esther 9:22), indicating two portions to one person. The verse continues: “And gifts to the poor” (Esther 9:22), indicating two gifts to two people.

**Are Bread + Hummus acceptable as the 2 Food portions? - Yes. Both are prepared & ready to eat | Megilla 7a:18 argues that a Pepper (or) any additional condiment may have greater significance due to its flavor.**

**Megillah 7a:18**

> וְהָא דְּרַבִּי יוֹסֵי בֶּן דּוֹרְמַסְקִית דִּלְמָא פְּרִיסְתָּקֵי שַׁדּוּר דִּשְׁמוּאֵל וַדַּאי לֵית לֵיהּ פִּירְכָא אָמַר רָבִינָא הַיְינוּ דְּאָמְרִי אִינָשֵׁי טָבָא חֲדָא פִּלְפַּלְתָּא חֲרִיפְתָּא מִמְּלֵי צַנֵּי קָרֵי

And that which Rabbi Yosei ben Durmaskit said with regard to the knowledge that no spoils were taken, perhaps this can be explained and refuted by the fact that they dispatched messengers who informed them of the situation. However, with regard to Shmuel’s proof from the fact that they confirmed above what they took upon themselves below, there is certainly no refutation. Ravina said: This explains the folk saying that people say: One sharp pepper is better than a basketful of pumpkins, as the quality of the pepper’s taste is more significant than the quantity of the pumpkins.

Comment: Your last quotation is from an entirely unrelated (though adjacent) discussion. It has nothing at all to do with mishloach manot

Comment: The פִּלְפֵּל was an example that חומוס could be a portion.

Comment: The problem is that they are not discussing mishloach manot at all. It just happens to be on the same page and also about food, but it has nothing to do with what constitutes a portion for mishloach manot